# Replacing ceiling fan/light combo with standard ceiling light to wall switch

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I'm replacing a ceiling fan/light combo, with a simple LED round flush "puff" ceiling light fixture. (1-blk, 1-wht, 1-grd)  *The wall switch only worked the ceiling fan light*. The wall switch currently is black to black, and white *was* connected to ceiling fan "light" wire.
What is the secret to having the wall switch get involved?
The junction box has blk/wht in from breaker, out to next room with ceiling fan, and incoming wall switch blk/wht.
Thanks so much...

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?  The fan installer did a no-no, but it should be pretty easy to fix

Comment: So did the fan not work before? Just the light? If this were the case, you would have black to blue(usually blue in a ceiling fan) and white to white. Unless your power comes to the ceiling box first, then to the switch, in which case you could have black to black and white to blue.

Comment: Thanks to "ThreePhase" & Jeff Cates for your response and interest in helping me. The fan only worked by the pull chain. The fan installer used the white as hot to create a loop through the wall switch, as Jeff described, because the power hits the ceiling box first.  The previous fan had the blue wire going to the wall switch white, with the fan white and black bypassing the wall switch.  I ended up wiring my light blk to wall switch wht, and wht to the "main" wht.  It works.  The fan was there for many years.  Should I try to undo original no-no? Don't know how to respond to you directly.